# Matlab. data in loop isn`t update

Tags: matlab

[Data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nfow.png)

Within the loop the variables `x1,x2,T1,T2,P1_sat,P2_sat, gamma1` are updated. However, `gamma2` isn't updated. I think the problem lies within the function `rr(gamma,T)`, but fail to see how this can be resolved.

There is no error thrown.

```
P = 101.33; y1 = 0.4; y2 = 0.6;
T1 = reverse_antoine1(P);
T2 = reverse_antoine2(P);dT = 0.01; Tf = 1000; n = round(Tf/dT);
x1 = 0.0001; x2 = 0.9999;T=0;gamma1 = 1.01;gamma2 = 1.01; 
T0 = 0;
for i = 1:n
    P1_sat = antoine1(T0);
    P2_sat = antoine2(T0);
    x1 = rr(gamma2,T0);
    x2 = 1 - x1;
    T1 = reverse_antoine1(P1_sat);
    T2 = reverse_antoine2(P2_sat);
    gamma1 = r1(x2, T0);
    gamma2 = r2(x1, T0);

     fprintf('\nIntermediate values at iteration %d: gamma2 = %.16f\n', i, gamma2);

    if ((abs(x1*gamma1*P1_sat + x2*gamma2*P2_sat - P)) < 0.1);
        T = T0;
        break;
    end

    T0 = T0 + dT;
end

function [gamma_1] = r1(x, T)
    A = 2.771 - 0.00523 * T;
    gamma_1 = exp(A*(x^2));
end

function [gamma_2] = r2(x, T)
    A = 2.771 - 0.00523 * T;
    gamma_2 = exp(A * x^2);
end

function [x] = rr(gamma, T)
    A = 2.771 - 0.00523 * T;
    x = sqrt(log(gamma)/A);
end

function [P_1_sat] = antoine1(T)
    P_1_sat = exp(16.59158 - 3643.31/(T - 33.424));
end

function [P_2_sat] = antoine2(T)
    P_2_sat = exp(14.25326 - 2665.54/(T - 53.424));
end

function [T1_0] = reverse_antoine1(P)
    T1_0 = 3643.31 / (16.59158 - log(P)) + 33.424;
end

function [T2_0] = reverse_antoine2(P)
    T2_0 = 2665.54 / (14.25326 - log(P)) + 53.424;
end
```

Why doesn't `gamma2` update?

Comment: Can you print a few intermediate values of `gamma2`? They might change, but with small increments.

Comment: With code 
' fprintf('\nIntermediate values at iteration %d: gamma2 = %.4f\n', i, gamma2);'
There is no change in gamma2 value in .4f.

Comment: Yea, give it 16 decimals. Please do [edit] the question with the results

Comment: With 16 decimals, There are no changes.....